# Show subtitles in YouTube embedded video in fullscreen mode

Tags: html, youtube-api, ionic-framework

guys!

I have mobile webapp with an YouTube embedded video and I can watch the video with the subtitles correctly in my smartphone. But, when I switch to fullscreen mode, the subtitles disappear and there are no controls to make them appear again.

I'm using the IFrame embed strategy, like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" 
    frameborder="0" width="560" height="315">
</iframe>
```

I tried to force it using the `cc_load_policy=1` flag, but it didn't work in fullscreen mode either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried reading regarding 'playsinline'? plasinline is a parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen. Here's the Official Google Documentation: (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en)